# Python run function in parallel to main code

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have the following code (Python 3.7 on windows 64bit):

```
from time import sleep
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

### function ###
def func(l):

     for i in l:
         sleep(1)
         print (i)
         t1 = time.time()
         total = t1-t0
         print ('time : ',total)


### main code ###
t0 = time.time()
l = list(range(1, 4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
     p = Process(target=func, args=(l,))
     p.start()
     p.join()

sleep(10)
print ('done')

t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print ('time : ',total)
```

The goal is to have a function run in parallel with the main block of code. When I run this I get the following result:

```
done
time :  10.000610828399658
1
time :  11.000777244567871
2
time :  12.001059532165527
3
time :  13.00185513496399
done
time :  23.11873483657837
```

However I was expecting the following:

```
1
time: ~1
2
time: ~2
3
time: ~3
done
time: ~10
```

So essentially I want the function to run in parallel with the main code. I am confused because without multiprocessing this code should run at most for 13 seconds but it is running for 23. The goal is to have it run in 10 seconds.

How can I fix this to have it work as intended?

Comment: Well, if you substract the 10s sleep...

Comment: @KlausD. I think that's the point: they expect the concurrent process to run while the sleep is happening, not wait until it's done.

Comment: The code seems fine, I am getting the expected o/p

1
time :  1.0074141025543213
2
time :  2.007577896118164
3
time : 3.0086448192596436
done
time :  13.015365839004517

Comment: Your code works fine. Probably your code slept 10s before forking the process.

Comment: Its worth mentioning I am running this on windows

Comment: Move the final time calculation inside __main__ so that it runs only after forking processes.

Comment: @Kaushal I get the same result with the final code inside `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: Ok so I get the proper (intended) result when I move the last 5 lines of code into the if __name__ == '__main__' nest, not sure why this fixes it though?

Comment: @MustardTiger Is this repeatable?  If you run this multiple times, do you get the same basic results?  They won't be exact, of course, but still, do you get 10ish, 11ish, etc?  I ask because your output doesn't match the code.  You print time 5 times, while the code only has it print 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post-processing results after multi-processing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195581/post-processing-results-after-multi-processing-in-python)

Comment: People not on Windows can change the start-method with `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` to get the same behaviour like the OP here observed (if spawn is supported on your OS).

Comment: @Scott Mermelstein Because the final print happens first in the child (reason in my link) and finally as expected in the parent. Would prefer to close it as dupe since it's just another incarnation of the linked question.

Comment: @Scott Mermelstein I thought so, thx. Only didn't remove my last comment because I wasn't sure if someone else needed the print-explanation.

Comment: @Scott Mermelstein There is only one child. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem where the first time printed is ~10, when I try it, I get times starting from ~1, as expected.

My final time from the parent process is ~13. This is because of `p.join()`, which waits for the child process to finish. If I remove that, the time printed in the parent is ~10.

Script:

```
from time import sleep
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

### function ###
def func(l):

     for i in l:
         sleep(1)
         print (i)
         t1 = time.time()
         total = t1-t0
         print ('time : ',total)


### main code ###
t0 = time.time()
l = list(range(1, 4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
     p = Process(target=func, args=(l,))
     p.start()
     # p.join()

sleep(10)
print ('done')
t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print ('time : ',total)
```

Output:

```
$ python testmultiproc.py 
1
time :  1.0065689086914062
2
time :  2.0073459148406982
3
time :  3.0085067749023438
done
time :  10.008337020874023
```